# Accessing /dev/mem freezes Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory, freeze, computer-forensics

I am using the latest Ubuntu Linux with a custom kernel (4.2.0-36-generic), in which i have disabled the CONFIG_STRICT_DEVNEM, because I need to dump and search some terms in memory during a project.

However, when using `dd if=/dev/mem` to print it on screen, `dd if=/dev/mem of=/home/user/Documents/file.dump` to save it as a file or `dd if=/dev/mem | hexdump -C | grep 'term'` to directly find what I'm looking for, the system freezes and reboots while in the process.

I have checked with `df -h` and my disc has plenty of free space. Also, the process always stops after writting a 2.1Gb to 2.5Gb, out of a 8Gb RAM and before reaching addresses that start with 4 (if these make any difference). In addition, checking `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/kern.log` shows nothing relevant before the freezing.

Also, using parameters `bs=1G count=2` successfully copies the first 2GB of the memory but then trying `bs=1G count=2 skip=2` to get then next 2GB again freezes the system.

Would you suggest any solution so it is possible to dump the full memory or some other way to directly search terms in memory?

Comment: [Check this on unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/119776/25786). I think the 'fmem' part would be the way to go

Comment: @ppeterka Trying now. Thanks

Comment: Run in parallel `tail -f /var/log/kern.log` and `tail -f /var/log/messages` to see if the kernel outputs a message before crashing.  Then, look at those files after the reboot. Also, [change the kernel's debug level](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelDebuggingTricks) to make it easier to see what the problem is. Consider asking the question on http://unix.stackexchange.com/ or http://askubuntu.com/.

Comment: @DiomidisSpinellis Even after changing the kernel's debug level to maximum, I could not find anything related or printed just before the crashing in `/var/log/kern.log` or `/var/log/syslog`. 

However, by asking on [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com) I got an [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/312089/accessing-dev-mem-freezes-ubuntu). By looking in `/var/log/kern.log` and `/proc/iomem' I found which memory areas are safe to access. 

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered on [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/312089/accessing-dev-mem-freezes-ubuntu/312092#312092) by ilkkachu, I was trying to access memory areas used by PCI/ACPI or some such hardware. Therefore I needed to access only "safe" memory areas.

So far, I can safely access the `(usable)` areas as shown on `/var/log/kern.log`:

```
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000020200000-0x000000003fffffff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000040000000-0x00000000401fffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000040200000-0x00000000c97e8fff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000c97e9000-0x00000000c9e81fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000c9e82000-0x00000000ca101fff] ACPI NVS
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000ca102000-0x00000000ca106fff] ACPI data
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000ca107000-0x00000000ca149fff] ACPI NVS
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000ca14a000-0x00000000cabb4fff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000cabb5000-0x00000000caff1fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000caff2000-0x00000000caffffff] usable
```

These areas can also be found as "System RAM" on `/proc/iomem`:

```
$ grep "System RAM" /proc/iomem
00001000-0009d7ff : System RAM
00100000-1fffffff : System RAM
20200000-3fffffff : System RAM
40200000-c97e8fff : System RAM
```

Therefore, I was able to `dd` these safe memory areas with multiple commands such as (for `20200000-3fffffff`):

```
dd if=/dev/mem of=Filename bs=230467520 count=1 skip=1 ibs=1075838980
```

(Note that the `ibs` is a few digits higher than the beginning of the memory area and the `bs` is a bit smaller than its size, as getting exactly all the "safe" area, caused the system to crash again.)

UPDATE:

Update: I can safely `dd` memory areas set as "System RAM", "RAM buffer" and "reserved".

Comment: The `dd` parameters you're using are a bit peculiar. For the first one I'd use `dd if=/dev/mem of=Filename bs=4096 count=8224 skip=8224` (bs = 0x1000, skip is 0x2020 and count is 0x4000-0x2020.  4000 is 0x3fff + 1)

Comment: Correct. Using `bs=1024 ibs=1024` and finding the count by dividing the addresses by that, I can get exactly what I need.